# Will a Gledhill Boilermate 2000 work with a Honeywell Evohome thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, boiler

Our flat uses a communal CHP system, with a [Gledhill Boilermate 2000](https://www.gledhill-boilermate.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/BoilerMate-2000-Manual.pdf) in our flat (i.e. we don't have direct access to a gas boiler).

We're looking to set up a Honeywell Evohome system consisting of a smart thermostat and radiator TRVs. We were wondering if our Boilermate can work with this, or if it's a non-starter.

There's an optional ATF500DHW Hot Water Kit available from Honeywell too. Would that work with the Boilermate too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thermostat and the radiator units worked fine. The hot water kit was not used.